# Files uploaded to hosting account but DNS is not finding the new files

Tags: web-hosting, dns, webserver, cpanel

I got a new domain `http://alfer-ks.com`. I have upload files to the server using cPanel, but when I try to load the website,  it just shows the cPanel default page, which shows that Apache is running and stuff like that.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

There is probably an index.html page in the root, most servers look for index.html then index.php then default.html and so on until they find one that works.

Find out what the default page is called by looking in your browser's address bar and delete it from the server along with it's associated files, then the correct page should load.

//Update

It seems [you're not alone](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/domain-redirecting-cgi-sys-defaultwebpage-cgi-139597.html) in having the defaultwebpage.cgi problem credit to @egillette for the fix...

Check your httpd.conf for an entry that looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs
    ServerAdmin webmaster@yourdomain.com
    UserDir disable
</VirtualHost>
```

Change it to (adding your IP in place of XXX. and so on)

```
<VirtualHost XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:80>
    ServerName www.yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/yourdom/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@yourdomain.com
    UserDir disable
</VirtualHost>
```

Then reboot the server and clear your browsers cache

Upload a .htaccess file containing the line

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

And you should be golden.

Comment: There is no index.html on the root, I deleted it, and I also tried to navigate to a different html file by typing the directory as url, but it returns a 404.

Comment: @user1008964 what kind of server are you on?

Comment: I am on a shared hosting server from dotyourdomain.com
It uses Apacha and has cpanel.

Comment: @user1008964 answer updated

Comment: Where can I find the httpd/conf file ?
I can't find the "/usr/local/apache/conf" directory.

Comment: Apache2 typically installs in `/etc/apache2/`

Comment: The etc directory is empty.

Comment: Do you have root access?

Comment: Erm, I'm not sure. My boss sent me the login details of the cpanel. It is hosten on dotyourdomain.com with the shared hosting 100mb plan.

Comment: Ok well then no you do not have root access and @toomanyairmiles comment doesn't apply since you do not have access to the apache2 server configuration files. Just delete everything in your public_html folder and upload a basic index.html files. Make sure the file permissions are set 744

Comment: @user1008964 this may be a wait and see issue - is this a recently added domain/addon domain like the others in the thread I linked to? I'd suggest you lodge a support ticket with your host, this may just be down to a time lag at the hosting end rather than a real bug.

Comment: Thanks both of you. Yes this is a recently added domain, on 13th of March. I will create a support ticked to cPanel. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @user1008964 no problem - I would expect some lag before an addon domain resolves correctly, but if it's been two days then it's probably a config error at the ISP end.

Answer (score 0):

You should browse your file system and look in your www or public_html folder you can delete the default.html or index.html file that is in there. After you upload your files be sure to clear you browser cache. You should also check that the permissions of the files you are uploading are readable by the server